# Node red MQTT node cannot connect to Azure IoT Hub

Tags: mqtt, azure, node-red

I am aware that there is [Azure IoT Hub palette](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-azure-iot-hub) in Node-red, which is specifically designed to interact with Azure IoT Hub. I tried that and it worked fine *most of the time*. However, due to an [instability issue](https://github.com/lcarli/NodeRedIoTHub/issues/23#issuecomment-448087319) I am curious to compare that palette with out-of-the box MQTT node provided by node-red.

I followed the instruction [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly), but I always got `connection failed to broker`. This happened both for the *publish* and *subscribe* node. I tried the same setting using `MQTT.js` following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51719672/5122657), and **it worked**, indicating that the credentials I am using is correct.

Here is my setting for the `subscribe` node:

**Node properties:**
*Topic*: `devices/{device_id}/messages/devicebound/#`
*QOS*: `1`

**Server properties:**
**Connection tab:**
*Server:* `<myhubname>.azure-devices.net`
*port:* `8883`
*enable SSL:* (checked)

**TLS config:**
*certificate:* (none)
*private key:* (none)
*passphrase:* (none)
*CA cert:* (the one from Baltimore cert)
*verify server certificate*: (checked) (I tried with unchecked but no difference)
*Server name*: none

**Security tab:**
*username:* `<myhubname>.azure-devices.net/<devicename>/api-version=2018-06-30`
*password:* (the SAS)

I also tried the node-red MQTT node to connect to AWS IoT, and it worked fine.

I understand that Azure IoT Hub is not a fully featured MQTT broker, but from my understanding it should be possible to connect to it using plain node-red MQTT node.

Am I missing something?  Thank you!

Comment: Did you succeed? I'm trying to do the same.